# Write a pure function to return one object from inner properties another objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, transformation, reduce

Doing some data transformation exercises and getting stuck. I have an object that I want to transform to look like`from (starting)` -> `to (expected ending)` output described below.  I'm trying to use `Array.reduce` and `Object.assign` to keep the output pure. but I just cannot get it to work properly.

```
/**
 *  from (starting): {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}}
 *  to (expected ending):   {topic: 2, products: 3}
 */

const starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};

const ending = Object.keys(starting).reduce((p, key) => {
  if(!p[key]) p[key] = key;
  return Object.assign(p[key], starting[key].id);  
}, {})
```

Comment: The arguments to `Object.assign()` have to be objects. `starting[key].id` is not an object. Neither is `p[key]`.

Comment: With a utility library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) this would be `const ending = _.mapValues(starting, 'id');`

Comment: @4castle yeah my excersize are basically teaching me these.. but I just couldn't do it... thanks for the higher order function name tho!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce`, just remember to return the starting object after each iteration.

```js
function convert(start) {
  return Object.keys(starting).reduce((o, key) => {
      o[key] = start[key].id;
      return o;
    }, {});
}

const starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};
console.log(convert(starting));
```

Comment: To make the function "pure", you probably want to return a new object on each iteration, rather than editing `o` each time

Comment: @nem035 `o` is the second argument passed to `reduce`, so is a new object just created for that.

Comment: yes, but a pure function technically shouldn't edit the arguments passed into it (i'm just being pedantic on the requirements, not saying anything is wrong with your approach, practically)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};

var ending = Object.keys(starting).reduce((p, key) => {
  p[key] = starting[key].id;
  return p;
}, {})
```

This will create a new object, so no need for `Object.assign` and such to keep the output pure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `reduce()` is the right tool for this.

Try iterating through `starting`'s keys using `forEach()` instead:

```js
const starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};

const ending = {};
Object.keys(starting).forEach(p => ending[p] = starting[p].id);

console.log(ending);
```

Comment: that's likely not correct since it's not "pure" (the arrow function within `forEach` has side effects)

Comment: yeah I didn't see the ending object above now that you mention it.  I still wanna solve this in a "pure" manner ... super struggling tho.  thanks for trying!

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice the "pure" requirement.  May delete, but the conversation is starting to get interesting.

Comment: Well, if you wrap the second and third line in a function, that function would be pure.

Comment: @nem035 Keeping code pure has its practical limits. A perfectly pure solution would make a new copy of the object with each iteration that has a single property changed. This function is so short that the impurities aren't dangerous.

Comment: @4castle of course it does, I'm going based of the question asking for a pure solution, not the practicality of it

Answer (score 2):

A pure function solution would require you to return a new object on each iteration:

```js
function convert(start) {
  return Object.keys(starting).reduce((o, key) => 
    Object.assign({}, {
      [key]: start[key].id
    }, o), {});
}

const starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};

console.log(convert(starting));
```

Using object spread makes it a bit cleaner:

```js
function convert(start) {
  return Object.keys(starting).reduce((o, key) => ({
    ...o,
    [key]: start[key].id
  }), {});
}

const starting = {topic: {id: 2}, products: {id: 3}};

console.log(convert(starting));
```